# Keyboard-Layout in Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm using Lubuntu and I'm not really able to get the keyboard-layout done. The  Keyboard Layout Handler ("Tastaturbelegungshandhaber") is in my panel but it's not active and I don't know how to add Russian as changeable language.

After trying a bit around all I could do is to have a German keyboard and when pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> the layout would become Russian.

I assume I need to sudo the Keyboard Layout Handler but the command `lxkeymap` doesn't seem to exist any more. The variant of adding the languages to Autostart doesn't seem to work either. How is it possible under this distro there is no convenient way to modify the preferred layout?

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` could restore my layout back to normal but I'm unable to add further keyboards.

[image]

Comment: Uncheck the "Systembelegungen beibehalten" option.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - I wonder how I oversaw that. Worked

Answer (score 1):

As [commentswered](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7023/are-people-getting-rep-shy-about-commentswers) by [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) [here:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050738/keyboard-layout-in-lubuntu#comment1715993_1050738)

Uncheck the "Systembelegungen beibehalten" option to resolve this issue.